# os.walk() strips polish characters

Tags: python

So what I'm trying to do is fix some id3tags of mp3 files. It all works, except for files with any kind of accent, because os.walk seems to strip them.

For example, I have the file `01.Co Słychać.mp3`, which in this code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    print files
```

Shows up as `['01.Co Slychac.mp3']`, later resulting in a 'No such file or directory' error.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Which Python (version number and source), and is it the Unicode version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you define `folder` as a Unicode string? This has implications on how `os.walk()` matches its subdirectories, or better, the type of string that it returns.

```
>>> for a,b,c in os.walk("."):
...  print b
...  break
...
['DLLs', 'Doc', 'include', 'Lib', 'libs', 'tcl', 'Tools']
>>> for a,b,c in os.walk(u"."):
...  print b
...  break
...
[u'DLLs', u'Doc', u'include', u'Lib', u'libs', u'tcl', u'Tools']
```

Comment: Great. I wonder why the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) doesn't mention this.

Comment: Ah, I see. `os.walk()` uses `os.listdir()`, and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) the docs explain this behaviour: "On Windows NT/2k/XP and Unix, if `path` is a Unicode object, the result will be a list of Unicode objects. Undecodable filenames will still be returned as string objects."

Comment: If only it was mentioned under os.walk >:(, would've saved me a lot of trouble. Thanks though!

Comment: Unfortunately, since the `nt` module (where `listdir()` lives) is built-in, we can't read the (Python) source for it. I guess it makes sense to return *something* instead of raising an exception, but if you then can't use that something except for display purposes, it's kind of frustrating. I'm so glad I'm on Python 3 where all these problems are gone.