# Read files with greek filenames

Tags: python, unicode

I am not a unicode expert, I read similar posts without any conclusive solution. I need a snippet to read some files with Greek characters. My files have names like

`20.10.2011 Ισοζύγιο Πληρωμών- Αύγουστος 2011.xls`

I have a generator function that yields filenames:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import os
import glob

def filesInDir(directory, mask='*.*'):
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(root, mask)):            
            yield file
```

Calling this:

```
for file in filesInDir(directory=r'.'):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        print f
```

gives

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: '.\\20.10.2011 ?s?????? ?????\xb5??- ?????st?? 2011.xls'
```

How do a create a valid file object using these sort of filenames?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that you call `os.walk()` with a Unicode string, or it will silently change non-ASCII letters to ASCII (or change them to `?` as you've observed).

So do

```
for file in filesInDir(directory=u'.'):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        print f
```

and

```
def filesInDir(directory, mask=u'*.*'):
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(root, mask)):            
            yield file
```

See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545511/os-walk-strips-polish-characters).

Comment: Don't forget to change the `mask` too.