# Python returns no such file or directory when opening a file it has just found using re.search

Tags: python, file, directory, ioerror

I am trying to open a specific file in many folders, with the name ending '.alleles.txt'. I search for the file and it is found, but then it returns:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abca3.alleles.txt'

when I try and open it.

```
for eachfile in filelisting:                       
    if re.search('\.alleles\.txt$', eachfile):
        allelesfile = open(eachfile, 'r')
        print '2'
```

Directory is specified by:

```
folder = 'E:\\All Data'
folderlisting = os.listdir(folder) 

for eachfolder in folderlisting:
    print eachfolder 
    if os.path.isdir(folder + '\\' + eachfolder):
        filelisting = os.listdir(folder + '\\' + eachfolder)
```

Comment: How do you create `filelisting`?

Comment: Also: use `os.path.join` instead of adding the "\\" separator. Otherwise your code will only run on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `glob`. Try this

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('E:\\All Data\\*\\*.alleles.txt')
```

Comment: The problem here is I want to open the file from each directory one at a time and then do things using other files in the same directory. I cant see how glob will allow me to match files from the same directory as easily.

Comment: you can get the directory part of a path via `os.path.dirname`

Answer (score 1):

How did you obtain the `filelisting`? If you used `filelisting = os.walk(directoryname)` then it resturns a special tuple. Did you look at it?

And, does `filelisting` contain the full path of the files? If the files are in a directory other than the script directory, say it's stored in the `directoryname` variable, you have to open them this way:

```
allelesfile = open(directoryname + "\\" + eachfile, 'r')
```

We can't give more information about your question until you put information here (actual `filelisting` value, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion that some of your filenames contain non-ASCII characters. Try

```
folder = u'E:\\All Data'
folderlisting = os.listdir(folder)

for eachfolder in folderlisting:
    print eachfolder 
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder,eachfolder)):
        filelisting = os.listdir(os.path.join(folder,eachfolder))
```

Note the `u'...'` prefix. Without it, `os.listdir()` might silently drop or ASCIIfy non-ASCII characters in your filenames, which then of course leads to invalid filenames. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545511/os-walk-strips-polish-characters).

This is stated in the [docs for `os.listdir(path)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) :

> On Windows NT/2k/XP and Unix, if `path` is a Unicode object, the result
>   will be a list of Unicode objects. Undecodable filenames will still be
>   returned as string objects.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears because it is trying to open the file from the directory where you are running the python program; and not the directory where the file resides.

You need to give `open` the full path to your file (including the directory name).