# How to use Python to replace all filenames that contain Chinese characters in several folders?

Tags: python, rename

The directory names and file names both contain Chinese characters. I'd like to be able to convert all to English version. I can make a dictionary of {chinese:english}, but have difficulties in getting file names with os.walk. Can someone help? I am new to python. Thanks.

Comment: > have difficulties in getting file names with os.walk... Which difficulties?

Answer (score 1):

When you say you're having trouble what exactly do you mean? Usually you use os.walk() as such:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path/to/directory'):
    [logic within each directory]
```

os.walk() creates a generator of tuples of the form (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) that will walk recursively through the current folder and all subsequent folders. You can then use the elements of files as filenames, dirs as directory names in the current directory, and root as the root directory for both files and directories. Then use os.rename(). See: [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: Thanks for replying. In my case, for folders containing Chinese characters, os.walk showed their names as '?????' and did not list their sub-folders or containing files. My understanding is that I will need to add some encode decode, but just can't make it work.

Comment: This post may help with the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545511/os-walk-strips-polish-characters